# Escrow contract that pays out to me. Should I hard code my wallet address?

Tags: solidity

I'm writing an escrow contract that pays out `0.01%` to my wallet of the total amount that both parties deposit into my contract.

This is how I make a bit of money to cover the costs of maintaining both the web and mobile app.

Would it be a bad idea to hardcode my wallet address into the contract? So that if the transaction between both parties is successful, the small fee can be sent to my wallet.

Comment: Rule of thumb it's always a bad idea. Why not have the standard setup of eg feeToSetter & feeTo like Uniswap Factory?

Comment: @Ake I'm a bit new to this, so I don't quite understand what you mean and what the feeTo does on Uniswap. Are you talking about instead of hardcoding it, I pass my wallet address through the constructor of the contract when it's first created?

Comment: I 'd add functions to change % and replace your wallet address for the payout

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE it can be a constructor for the initial state that can be changed to a different address later too through a public function. Let me provide you with an example in the answer section.

Comment: Thanks for the help you guys, appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hardcoding, it's always a good idea to have some flexibility to be able to change the address the fee is paid to.

Here's a quick simple contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract SimpleEscrow {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    address public owner;
    address public feeRecipient;
    uint256 public totalDeposits;
    bool public released = false;
    uint256 constant FEE_PERCENTAGE = 1; // 0.01%

    // Set the initial fee recepient on deployment
    constructor(address _feeRecipient) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        feeRecipient = _feeRecipient;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the owner can call this function");
        _;
    }

    function deposit() external payable {
        require(!released, "Funds released");
        totalDeposits = totalDeposits.add(msg.value);
    }

    function release() external onlyOwner {
        require(!released, "Funds released");
        
        uint256 feeAmount = totalDeposits.mul(FEE_PERCENTAGE).div(10000); // Calculate 0.01% fee
        payable(feeRecipient).transfer(feeAmount);

        uint256 remainingAmount = totalDeposits.sub(feeAmount);
        payable(owner).transfer(remainingAmount);

        released = true;
    }

    // Change the fee recepient to any other addressl only contract owner can do this
    function setFeeRecipient(address _newFeeRecipient) external onlyOwner {
        feeRecipient = _newFeeRecipient;
    }
}
```

You can set the fee recipient through the constructor on the deployment. And then the contract owner (contract deployer) can change the fee recipient to a different address at any time.

The code is a working example, but don't use it in prod of course XD